# Angular2 TypeScript - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/forms'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

My component file contains:

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<user></user>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {

}
```

My app.modules :

```html
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angluar/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ,FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, UserComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when i try to compile my code i got this error : **error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/forms'**
Thanks!

Comment: please add your package.json file, I think you're just missing @angular/forms as dependency.

Comment: His already existing in package.json

Comment: Are you using angular-cli? webpack or system.js? is the folder "forms" present in "node_modules/@angular"?

Comment: did you installed it ? `npm install @angular/forms --save`

Comment: the foldar is present in node_modules/@angular

Comment: I installed angular2  from github https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in *angular*:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angluar/forms';
```

should be:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: PS. I assume you have written the error message longhand, as angular is correctly spelled there ;)

Answer (score -1):

You have errors in your code
check the new one here:

```html
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ,FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, UserComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: eeh, how is this different from my answer? :D You just made the same change as I pointed out ;)

Comment: what a coincidence!